# A small problem that I cannot detect, My steppers are not moving for some reason ...?

Tags: programming, electronics, stepper, robotics

I'm working on a similar project that can be found in this link 
https://howtomechatronics.com/projects/arduino-mecanum-wheels-robot/
It's the same build.
To control the 4 steppers (via the NRF24L01), I have built a remote control ( and you can find the project on the same website).
I have modified a few things and kept on testing on each step that I go through. 
For now: my remote control sends X, Y from 1 joystick module and X1, Y1 from a second joystick module, besides mapped value from a potentiometer.
Back to the car, I'm receiving the exact same data and all works fine.
I have tested my circuit, 
the power supply is fine and all good.
But I'm facing a problem that I could not detect when it comes to making the steppers move after receiving the data from the transmitter.
This is the code I m using for the receiver: 
I'm not familiar with this Library and I feel like I'm only missing a small detail.
(As I said the same circuit was tested with a different code and steppers are running just fine).
Hopefully, you can help me out and spot what's wrong.
Thanks a lot guys.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <AccelStepper.h>
 RF24 radio(7, 8);   // nRF24L01 (CE, CSN)
const byte address[6] = "00001";
//unsigned long lastReceiveTime = 0;
//unsigned long currentTime = 0;
// Define the stepper motors and the pins the will use
AccelStepper LeftBackWheel(1, 2, 3);   // (Type:driver, STEP, DIR) - Stepper1
AccelStepper LeftFrontWheel(1, 4, 5);  // Stepper2
AccelStepper RightBackWheel(1, 9, 10);  // Stepper3
AccelStepper RightFrontWheel(1, 41, 40); // Stepper4
int wheelSpeed = 1500;
// Max size of this struct is 32 bytes - NRF24L01 buffer limit
struct Data_Package {
  byte j1PotX;
  byte j1PotY;
  byte j2PotX;
  byte j2PotY;
  byte pot1;

};
Data_Package data; //Create a variable with the above structure
void setup() {
  // Set initial seed values for the steppers
  LeftFrontWheel.setMaxSpeed(3000);
  LeftBackWheel.setMaxSpeed(3000);
   RightFrontWheel.setMaxSpeed(3000);
  RightBackWheel.setMaxSpeed(3000);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  //radio.setAutoAck(false);
  //radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.startListening(); //  Set the module as receiver
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  // Check whether we keep receving data, or we have a connection between the two modules
  /*currentTime = millis();
    if ( currentTime - lastReceiveTime > 1000 ) { // If current time is more then 1 second since we have recived the last data, that means we have lost connection
    resetData(); // If connection is lost, reset the data. It prevents unwanted behavior, for example if a drone jas a throttle up, if we lose connection it can keep flying away if we dont reset the function
    }*/
  // Check whether there is data to be received
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(Data_Package)); // Read the whole data and store it into the 'data' structure
    //lastReceiveTime = millis(); // At this moment we have received the data
  }

  Serial.print("X1= ");
  Serial.print(data.j1PotX);
  Serial.print("  Y1= ");
  Serial.println(data.j1PotY);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("X2= ");
  Serial.print(data.j2PotX);
  Serial.print("  Y2= ");
  Serial.println(data.j2PotY);
  Serial.println(" POT1=  ");
  Serial.println(data.pot1);
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
  // Set speed - left potentiometer
  wheelSpeed = map(data.pot1, 0, 255, 100, 3000);


  if (data.j1PotX > 150) {
    moveSidewaysLeft();
  }
  else if (data.j1PotX < 100) {
    moveSidewaysRight();
  }
  else if (data.j1PotY > 160) {
    moveForward();
  }
  else if (data.j1PotY < 100) {
    moveBackward();
  }
  else if (data.j2PotX < 100 & data.j2PotY > 160) {
    moveRightForward();
  }
  else if (data.j2PotX > 160 & data.j2PotY > 160) {
    moveLeftForward();
  }
  else if (data.j2PotX < 100 & data.j2PotY < 100) {
    moveRightBackward();
  }
  else if (data.j2PotX > 160 & data.j2PotY < 100) {
    moveLeftBackward();
  }
  else if (data.j2PotX < 100) {
    rotateRight();
  }
  else if (data.j2PotX > 150) {
    rotateLeft();
  }
  else {
    stopMoving();
  }
  // Execute the steps
  LeftFrontWheel.runSpeed();
  LeftBackWheel.runSpeed();
  RightFrontWheel.runSpeed();
  RightBackWheel.runSpeed();
}
void moveForward() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
}
void moveBackward() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
}
void moveSidewaysRight() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
   RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
}
void moveSidewaysLeft() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
}
void rotateLeft() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
   RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
}
void rotateRight() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);

  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
   RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
}
void moveRightForward() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(0);
  RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(0);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
}
void moveRightBackward() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(0);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(0);
}
void moveLeftForward() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(0);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
   RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(wheelSpeed);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(0);
}
void moveLeftBackward() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(0);
  RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(0);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(-wheelSpeed);
}
void stopMoving() {
  LeftFrontWheel.setSpeed(0);
  LeftBackWheel.setSpeed(0);
   RightFrontWheel.setSpeed(0);
  RightBackWheel.setSpeed(0);
}
void resetData() {
  // Reset the values when there is no radio connection - Set initial default values
  data.j1PotX = 127;
  data.j1PotY = 127;
  data.j2PotX = 127;
  data.j2PotY = 127;
  data.pot1 = 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you should not use delay here. Ditch that delay call. You can time the LCD display like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example

Comment: I will try that for sure